# Mockito and jUnit for mocking utilities with REST

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Code:

```
public class AccountService(){

private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public Account getAccount(){
    try {

        ClientResponse response = RestUtility.getAccounts();

        if(CLientResponse.OK.Status == response.getClientResponseStatus()){
            return mapper.readValue(response.getEntity(String.class), Account.class)
        } 

    } catch(Exception e){
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return null;
    }
}
```

How can I mock this service? The RestUtility is a static utility and cannot be mocked by mockito. All I want is for my method to return a list of 'mock' accounts. Is it even possible with this architecture?

Comment: Use PowerMock with mockito to mock static methods
https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock statick method you cna use `PowerMock`.
Or you can create wrapper on your `RestUtility` class.
Reference to this wrapper should be provided on constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you change to

```
public class AccountService() {
    protected ClientResponse getResponse() { return RestUtility.getAccounts(); }

    public Account getAccount() {
        try {
            ClientResponse response = getResponse();
            ...
        }
}
```

it is trivial to mock out `getResponse()` using Mockito or other mock frameworks. Or even easier:

```
public class AccountServiceTest {
    class TestableAccountService extends AccountService {
        @Override
        protected ClientResponse getResponse() { return <yourmockresponsegoeshere>; }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        AccountService ac = new TestableAccountService();
        assertThat( ac.getAccount.size() , equalTo( 1 ) );
        // etc
        ...
    }
```

Cheers,